# How can we change the jar file from one version to another? selenium

Tags: selenium, testing

I want to change the selenium java jar file. I deleted the one old and insert a new one however it is still saying it cannot find the old one.

I have changed in update-config.json file inC:\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium folder but it still not working.

I want to know where this jar is referenced when doing selenium testing.

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

From selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar to 
selenium-server-standalone-2.51.1.jar

Comment: Any typical business case for downgrading Selenium?

Comment: naming issue,, what is the name of the file you have deleted and you have added? is the both names are same?

Comment: @DebanjanB, selenium 3.4.0 doesn't support firefox 45.5.1 so trying to drop down to selenium 2.51.1

Comment: @santhoshkumar, From selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar to selenium-server-standalone-2.51.1.jar

Comment: Rename the new file name similar to the deleted nama

Comment: @santhoskumar, didn't work that way either.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the version webdriver-manager downloads by altering Protractor's config.json file...

1. Edit Protractor's config file: *node_modules/protractor/config.json*
2. Change the selenium version to whatever you need. eg. *"selenium": "2.47.1"*,
3. Run *webdriver-manager update*

You should be good to go.